# Julia - equivalent of recursive sapply function in R

Tags: r, recursion, julia

I had a function in R (`onestep` below) which took as an argument a vector `v` and returned a new vector `v` as output which was a function of the input vector. I then iterated this function `niter` times and kept the output vectors of each iteration (which are not all the same length and can occasionally also end up having length 0) in another function `iterate` as follows (minimal example) :

```
onestep = function (v) c(v,2*v)
iterate = function (v, niter) sapply(1:niter, function (iter) {v <<- onestep(v)
                                                               return(v) } )
```

Example :

```
v=c(1,2,3)
iterate(v,3) 

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 2 4 6

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  2  4  6  2  4  6  4  8 12

[[3]]
 [1]  1  2  3  2  4  6  2  4  6  4  8 12  2  4  6  4  8 12  4  8 12  8 16 24
```

I was wondering what would be a compact and idiomatic way to do such a recursive function that returns all the intermediate results in Julia? Any thoughts? (Apologies if this is trivial but I am new to Julia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure on the compact and idiomatic front, but this is how I'd do it

```
onestep(v) = [v 2*v]

function iterate(v, niter)
    Results = Array(Array, niter)
    Results[1] = onestep(v)
    for idx = 2:niter
        Results[idx] = onestep(Results[idx - 1])
    end
    Results
end

v = [1 2 3]
iterate(v, 3)
```

Comment: Many thanks - that's perfect for me! The sapply with v set as a global variable was a little dodgy anyway :-) Thanks so much for your kind help!

Comment: @TomWenseleers Sure thing.  Also, in general, as you move from R to Julia, you'll find that you do a lot of things based on looping of all sorts, which is generally faster than vectorizing.  Thus, in a lot of cases, things like `sapply` just won't be coming into your mind so much.  Also, if you're looking for performance and coming from an R background, I highly recommend reading the Julia performance guides and in particular paying careful attention to type casting in your functions (which I didn't do here for simplicity of exposition).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way that is a bit more concise and more truly recursive, as per your original question:

```
v = Array[[1, 2, 3]] ## create v as an array of one dimensional arrays
function iterate(v::Array{Array, 1}, niter::Int)
    niter == 0 && return v[2:end]
    push!(v, [v[end] ; 2v[end]])
    niter -= 1
    iterate(v, niter)
end

iterate(v, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, +1 - although I think I still prefer your other solution more in terms of readability. My final little Julia program is here, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134926/simulating-evolution-of-a-trait-in-an-asexual-population, in case you would like to comment on the way I coded it, or if you would see any obvious ways to boost performance...

Comment: @TomWenseleers Yeah, I'm with you on the readability and having simple, intuitive code rather than trying to find the most idiomatic and concise ways of doing things every time.  I code in a lot of languages and so generally prefer solutions that are based on implementing a few simple and universal principals of coding.